# How to insert data in elastic search using ruby

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, rubygems

I am trying to insert data using elastic search PUT with the Elasticsearch gem in ruby, but I am getting method not found error.

```
Here is the sample code:

 def self.insert_data_in_es
   name = (here I am giving the url)
   body = (actual data)
   Elasticsearch::API::Indices::Actions.put_template(name: name, body: 
   body)

end

Error :
NoMethodError: undefined method `put_template' for Elasticsearch::API::Indices::Actions:Module
```

Is there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because `Actions` is just a module, included in `Elasticsearch::API::Indices::IndicesClient`.

You should initialize your client and call it like this:

```
client.indicies.put_template(args)
```

Anyways, I highly recommend you to have a look at [chewy](https://github.com/toptal/chewy). It's very cool elasticsearch gem, maintained by toptal.